# How to add data to filtered list in Searchview from Recyclerview in Realtime

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I want to search items in adapter which are added after 15 seconds (postDelayed runnable method , applied *Looper.getMainlooper* also doesn't help) were visible in list for that i have used *NotifyDataSetChanged* in adapter but in search it doesn't appear.

**What i have tried so far :**  I launched the app as i have given 15 seconds delayed then i directly jumped to searchview i typed this item name then not found but what i want is to add that

**What i want to achieve :**   add updated adapter's data into  filteredlist in realtime.So, that in searchview it will receive updated data.

**Github Repo Link :** https://github.com/AbhishekTiwariAndroid/Searchviewjava

Comment: Try Textwatcher on OnTextchange method set notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: means i wrote a text in searchview if it is not found then when it is found then show it.

Answer (score 1):

Just added one line after adding a new item to an existing list in postdelayed
**filter(searchView.getQuery().toString());**

```
new Handler( ).postDelayed(new Runnable( ) {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        courseModelArrayList.add(new CourseModel("Cosmic", "Trade share market"));
                        System.out.println("cosmic " );

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        filter(searchView.getQuery().toString());
                    }
                },5000);
```

Comment: You can test with properly by increasing postDelayed time from 5000 to 15000 milliseconds. so it will show the proper realtime result on search items.

Comment: i have checked this but not useful.